# Nodemon Keeps Restarting After I Kill the PID

Tags: node.js, centos, nodemon

I have a server running CentOS with nodemon 1.19.1 and node v10.16.0. Nodemon, for some reason keeps restarting a node on a particular file that I have assigned to port 3019.

I have tried pulling up the process by the port, by the node process name, and killed it, many times, but it comes back without fail.

I did try a server restart, and that worked for a few hours, but the problem persists. After the restart, I made sure that I didn't abandon any sessions on the server and Ctrl C to kill nodemon, but alas, here I am.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're running on CentOS 7.x then the systemd file for nodemon (.service) has a restart cmd which will restart it automatically if killed off.  Either disable the service or remove the line which restarts it in the .service file.

Comment: Although I appreciate your help, Nodemon isn't running as a service on the server. After seeing your comment, I searched for something along those lines. I am able to account for all of the running services, and cannot find any mention of it in any of the services.

Comment: OK, have you tried looking at the process tree? `ps -ejH` to see if it will show you additional information about the process that keep coming back??

Comment: So, I learned a little about nodemon and it appears that it is doing exactly what it should do....https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon      `nodemon is a tool that helps develop node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.`

Comment: @GoinOff thanks again for your help, sorry I was out of signal all day yesterday. I tried the process tree, I don't see nodemon in there, I do see Node, so I guess my bigger question is how to kill the watching. I know that it is supposed to restart, but it isn't restarting like it is supposed to once it is closed.

I am probably not making too much sense in this comment, but I have closed Nodemon, or so I thought, and it is still starting up Node. However, it won't restart Node on file changes now, instead I have to kill the Node process.

Comment: You're welcome.. Maybe this link will help ??? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163603/how-to-find-source-of-spawning-process